# Integral involving exponential function and lower incomplete gamma function

Tags: gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, integration

Can we get the closed form value of the integral
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax}\gamma(x,b)dx,
\end{equation*}
here, $a$ is a positive real numbers and $b$ is positive integer. Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: It could be done using infinite series

Comment: The integral diverges.